# Weird effect on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress theme and have scanned through the javascript files but can't figure out what is causing this.

When the page is loading there is this odd zoom effect, then everything returns to normal. Happens in most browsers but sometimes doesn't happen in Safari.

Take a look:

http://homestudiocenter.com/homestudiocourse/

Any ideas what it might be?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you add screenshots? some users don't look at links.

Comment: dont post random links, use screenshots or show some code

Comment: I can't duplicate it.

Comment: I have the zoom w/ Chrome. Have you seen the inspector error around `
 <style>
@media (max-width: 320px) {
   .hentry .alignleft, .hentry .alignright {
     float: right !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
}
</style>` that's not the zoom origin I guess but...

Comment: If I had to guess...

`body * {
    animation-duration: 0.001s;
    animation-name: insQ_101;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.001s;
    -webkit-animation-name: insQ_101;
}`

Comment: it zoombugs w/ Chrome & Safari, not FFOX. Webkit issue ?

Answer (score 1):

i think its been caused by the css inside class `home`. The zooming effect happens when you remove and add `home` css to body.

The definition is

```
.home {
    background-image: url('images/mac.png');
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 730px;
    animation: animatedBackground 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

The definition for `animatedBackground` is

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from {
        background-position: center 550px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: center bottom;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body * { animation-duration: 0.001s; animation-name: insQ_101; -webkit-animation-duration: 0.001s; -webkit-animation-name: insQ_101; }
```

**This webkit animation is the source of it.** This explains why it zooms on Safari & Chrome (webkit) and not FFox (non-webkit).

Comment: Thnx for stealing my answer :)

Comment: @Aibrean you have the definition of `insQ_101` ?

Comment: @Aibrean You re welcome. This is a lesson about ≠ce between *andwer* and *comment*. Post your own, I delete mine. My charity.

Comment: I do have the definition, but if @Aibrean wants to answer, s/he should have too.

Comment: @Strukt : for me it zooms in FireFox also. Version is 40.0

Comment: Indeed, the animation is also non-webkit. `animation-duration: 0.001s; animation-name: insQ_101;` . IF it is this animation. more about insQ_101 ?

Comment: LOL It's no big deal.